# How to call array data corresponding to same array's id

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array where each element refers to a bunch of svgs in another js file. I'm trying to get it so that my alert message uses the same string I use in the array variable.

```
var illustArr = ['map', 'privacy', 'payment', 'rewards', 'passcode'];

var bmAnim = document.getElementById('illus-'+illustArr[i]);    

bmAnim.addEventListener('click', function(){
    alert('illus-'+illustArr[i]);
});
```

Any ideas how to achieve that?

Comment: sample output for the current code and for what you expect would be appreciated!

Comment: Where is your for loop?  You don't appear to be iterating through your array with i.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using a `for-loop`. Also make sure that you check if element exists so that you wont get an error.

```js
var illustArr = ['map', 'privacy', 'payment', 'rewards', 'passcode'];

for (var i = 0; i < illustArr.length; i++) {
    bmAnim = document.getElementById('illus-' + illustArr[i]);
    
  if (bmAnim) { //check if element exists
    bmAnim.addEventListener('click', function() {
     alert('illus' + this.id);
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="illus-map">MAP</div>
<p>
  <div id="illus-privacy">PRIVACY</div>
  <p>
    <div id="illus-payment">PAYMENT</div>
    <p>
      <div id="illus-rewards">REWARDS</div>
      <p>
        <div id="illus-passcode">PASSCODE</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over the array and assign the click function with the corresponding key in scope.

```
var illustArr = ['map', 'privacy', 'payment', 'rewards', 'passcode'];

illustArr.forEach(function (key) {
  var bmAnim = document.getElementById('illus-' + key);

  bmAnim && bmAnim.addEventListener('click', function () {
    alert('illus-' + key);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `Array#forEach` function to iterate over the elements in your array before you attach any listeners to the `click` event. Also, you can use `this.id` in the event handler to reference the string `illus-*` with the desired suffix rather than accessing `illustArr` again.

```js
var illustArr = ['map', 'privacy', 'payment', 'rewards', 'passcode'];

illustArr.forEach(function (e) {
  document.getElementById('illus-' + e).addEventListener('click', handler)
})

function handler () {
  alert(this.id)
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li id="illus-map">Map</li>
  <li id="illus-privacy">Privacy</li>
  <li id="illus-payment">Payment</li>
  <li id="illus-rewards">Rewards</li>
  <li id="illus-passcode">Passcode</li>
</ul>
```